# Qual a função do $$ nas funções do posntegresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

Olá, sou iniciante em postegrsql e tenho a seguinte duvida: 
 
Quando criamos funções no postgresql geralmente é usada a seguinte lógica

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION func() RETURNS ret AS $$ 
BEGIN
...
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Pelo que li os $$ são delimitadores do corpo da função, gostaria de saber se o que esta entre os dois $ tem alguma função a mais. Já vi funções onde é usado apenas **$$**, onde é usado **$BODY$** ou também **$*nome_da_função*$**. Isso interfere alguma coisa na função ou no schema? Existe algum padrão de mercado?

Comment: O uso de $$ ou $alguma coisa$ é apenas um facilitador para delimitar o corpo da função. Nas versões antigas usava-se o corpo da função entre apóstrofes (') mas isso criava um problema se o no corpo da função você necessitasse utilizar o apóstrofe sendo necessário duplicar ou quadruplicar para funcionar corretamente. Ah!, e o nome é PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No PostgreSQL os cifrões são usados para substituir aspas simples, em funções definidas pelos usuários e stored procedures. Em alguns casos é difícil entender quando a string tem muitas aspas simples ou barras invertidas, porque elas precisam ser duplicadas. Então, para ficar mais legível a query, ele fornece esse uso de $$ para escrever as constantes. O corpo de funções também devem ser colocados entre aspas simples, portanto pode ser substituído por $$.